# Discrepancy found in font size in iOS and Android devices developed using Flutter

Tags: flutter

We have developed a flutter app for Android and iOS. the android version is working fine but when tested on iOS the same font size looks horribly wrong... it appears too big.

on the simulator it looks fine though.

We are using `Lexend` and the font has been included in the `pubspec.yml` file also.

```
  fonts:
    - family: Lexend
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lexend.ttf
  uses-material-design: true
```

and the file is also included in the mentioned folder.

Is there anything else which need to be done to ensure parity between the platforms?

Am sure this is a problem faced and solved by other developers also, just that I am not sure what it is.

edit-

image from simulator is as follows:

[image: Image from simulator (iphone 14)]

image from device is as follows:

[image: Image from device (iphone X)]

The accessibility settings seems to be okay and other apps are working fine.

Comment: Check the accessibility settings of the iPhone. It might have larger fonts (scaling) enabled.

Comment: the accessibility settings are fine. :(